# Why the text in nav-links are not appearing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs but the text in the nav links are not appearing. Do you know why?

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/o1w0m4os/

HTml:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray" role="tablist">
    <li class="">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">tab 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block">tab 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-block"> tab 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put this class `d-none` what says in css `display: none!important;` 
so remove `d-none`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills bg-light-gray" role="tablist">
    <li class="">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-lg-inline-block">tab 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-lg-inline-block">tab 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" name="myCongresses" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">
            <span class="d-lg-inline-block"> tab 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```